# Solving a recurrence relation in general involving multiplying 2 consecutive terms?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given a "quadratic" recurrence form:
$$A = (a_{n+1}-B)(a_n-C)$$
How do I determine the general solution? I've been trying for about an hour now. If I could have a small hint that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason to expect it to have a "closed form" solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, solve for $a_{n+1}$ as an expresson in $a_n$. This is a linear fractional (Möbius) transformation. See the Wikipedia article [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) As such, there are either two fixed points, or else one fixed point. These two possibilities lead to simple recurrence relations for $a_n$. In the first case, you transform the fixed points to $0$ and $\infty$, and in the second case, to $\infty$. It is easier to see this in reverse. Suppose we define by recursion $\;a_{n+1}:=f(a_n)\;$ for some function $f(x).\;$ In the first case, we let $f(x):=cx.\;$ Then $a_n$ forms a geometric progression. In the second case, we let $f(x):=c+x.\;$ Then $a_n$ forms an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Can you expand a little on that last line? After I have the fixed points how do I get recurrence relations for $a_n$.